# PHP Regular Expression allow "a-z" & "1-9" & "-" & minimum one or maximum two "." between chars

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a PHP RegEx that allow "a-z" & "A-Z" & "-" & "."

- "." is allow to use minimum 1 and maximum 2 times and not together ".."
- "-" may use many times but not together "--" and cannot use after
  last dot "."

in other words I want to validate domain or sub-domain name like:

**my-domain.com** or **sub.my-domain.com**

and for eg: my--domain.com or my-domain.com-net or my-domain-.com or etc must return false.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/', $odomain)) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Use more than one regular expression.

Comment: `my--domain.com` and `my-domain.com-net` are perfectly valid domain names. `my-domain-.com` is not valid but not because it contains two dashes (`-`). It is not valid because the rules of valid domain names are different: each component is allowed to contain at most 63 characters. The allowed characters are letters (`a-z`, case doesn't matter), digits (`0-9`) and dashes (`-`) but the dashes but the component is not allowed to start or end with a dash.

Comment: The question talks about adjacent hyphens `--` not having two hyphens in a domain component.  Read RFC-1035 for the exact grammar allowed (yes, it's a regular grammar, so it has a regexp)

Comment: `0` is not allowed in a regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure domains and TLDs do not contain Unicode characters you may want to try:

```
(?i)^[a-z\d]+([.-][a-z\d]+)*\.[a-z]+$
```

This matches `user.sub.domain.com` too (disregarding first rule which I didn't consider valid)

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/4a0ryC/2)

PHP code:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z\d]+([.-][a-z\d]+)*\.[a-z]+$/i', $domain);
```

Comment: You can be sure completely.  Utf is not allowed in a plain domain name, only chars in the set `[a-zA-Z0-9-]`.  There's an RFC talking about valid domain names, but I don't remember the number now.

Comment: It is RFC-1035 , sorry for the delay

Comment: You should read about [*Internationalized Domain Name*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) @LuisColorado

Comment: yes... i've done @revo, and that is a way to encode international domain names into old style RFC-1035.  The difference is that that is a best practices to encode internationalized domain names.... the other is the standard syntax of a valid domain name.... it only uses chars in the group `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` ASCII encoded (7bit).

Comment: An IDN has not to be represented as in ASCII characters but it has to be translated to ASCII representation when a DNS lookup on network is going be performed. You can fill a form field with an IDN which someone may want to consider to validate. @LuisColorado

Comment: yes.... so you are giving me the right.... you enter domains in whatever codeset you use locally, then you convert it to ASCII, and process it (let's say do a dns lookup, or extract the domainname ---with a regexp--- from the url the browser uses to query the server)

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say with your other comments but all these comments were about your first one.

Comment: DNS  is a network service, it has existed for long long time in internet.  It was specified with ascii charset, and continues to use it.  Valid domain names are only ascii, not allowing for extended charsets.  The functionality you describe goes up to the application and presentation levels and doesn't have anything with the data processing that domain processors do with on the wire domain names.  Anything the regexp solves at low level can be seen without problem at high presentation level.  So I'm right, the regexp does not depend on the user charset.  The one presented is valid.

Comment: What I mean is that the regexp you use does never depend on the charset you are using for presentation purposes, as IDN encodes utf characters in 5bit chunks to allow to represent them in the set [A-Z0-9-] which is the only character set allowed in a domain.

Comment: I think you are having a hard time to understand what I'm talking about as I can see you are not on the right track. I said earlier in answer to aware OP if he / she is dealing with domains like http://www.اسکریپت.com (like having them in a large input text or an input field) they wouldn't want to work with this regex in the answer.

Comment: Not. You are indeed not understanding me.... What I mean is that if you encode that domain into some software, and you punyencode it to be able to access the urll (which needs a correctly formatter ascii domain name) you ***can use a charset independent*** regular expression to extract the domain name, and then punydecode it to get the presentatio string you have put in your last example.

Comment: You are talking about *conditions* whether they should be done. Why do you think OP is able to work around these conditions? Can you understand me? @LuisColorado

Answer (score 1):

Use the following

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)+
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4bx3uV/1) for details. **Note** that in the examples you post, my--domain.com or my-domain.com-net or my-domain-.com do have valid domain names, as shown in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4bx3uV/1).

## edit

After revising [RFC-1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035) I've seen that the requirement you post to disallow to adjacent `-` chars is not valid, as it is perfectly valid to use two hyphens together, with care they don't get to the sides.  So [the edited regexp](https://regex101.com/r/4bx3uV/2) should be:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*)+
```

Comment: `my-domain-.com` is not a valid domain name.

Comment: No, it isnt'. Try it and you'll se how it is rejected.  But it is `my--domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

After hours improve the RegEx and think this is working well:

```
/^(?!\-)(?:[a-zA-Z\d\-]{0,62}[a-zA-Z\d]\.){1,126}(?!\d+)[a-zA-Z\d]{1,63}$/
```

Comment: Your regex is much complicated and doesn't match your requirements as it matches `my--domain.com`.

Comment: yes, you're right. thanks. your code works very well.

Comment: @revo, multiple `-` together are allowed in a domain name component.  The complexity of a regex must not scare you, as it is not written for human readability, but for computer interpretation.